# Download item on web page from command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, download, html

I need to download the 138GB tar file from the following [link](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/nonpub-downloads)

And I need to download it from my AWS instance.

I've tried `wget image-net.org/path_to_tar`

But that gives a 404. So I also tried `wget image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/nonpub-downloads/path_to_tar` and that downloads an empty tar file

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`wget` works perfectly. You misspelled a part of the URL: **nnoupb**

```
wget http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2012/nnoupb/ILSVRC2012_img_train.tar
```